# Flask, Jinja2 - missing a positional argument, but I have supplied multiple

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have been stuck on this error for quite some time.  I am new to Jinja2 and Flask, but I have tried messing around with my for loop and editing things in my `main.py` to no avail.  Here's what I've got so far.

First, my `main.py`

```
# Data Science Notes Route
@app.route('/data-science/<content>')
def note(content):   
    return render_template('notes.html', content=content)
```

Next, the part of my template that is causing the error.

````
{% for link in category_files %}

    <h2 class="file-title"><a href="{{ url_for('note', content=get_note_content(link)) }}"
            class="file-link">{{ note_dict[link].title }}</a></h2>

    <!-- Display a description of the file -->
    <p class="file-description">{{ note_dict[link].description }}</p>

    <!-- Display the topics covered -->
    <p class="file-topics">Topics covered: {{ note_dict[link].topics }}</p>

    <!-- Display an image -->
    <img src="{{ note_dict[link].image }}" alt="">

    {% endfor %}```

The issue is that very first part with the `a` tag.  According to the error message, I am missing the **content** argument.  But it looks to me like I'm not!  Here's the error output, as well as the `dump()` output. 

[![Image of Error][1]][1]

Any aid would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyqN0.png
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't included `filepath` in your URL route.

```
@app.route('/<note_title>/<filepath>', methods=['GET'])
def note(note_title, filepath):
    ....
```

If you want filepath as a url parameter then:

```
from flask import request
@app.route('/<note_title>', methods=['GET'])
def note(note_title):
    filepath = request.args.get('filepath')
    ....
```

Comment: This is a great answer so I'm gonna accept it, but I don't think I explained my issue well.  I'm gonna accept this and try a repost with better explanation.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Only accept it if it actually answers your question. But for further clarification, you are supplying `filepath`, but when you place arguments inside the function parentheses, they need to appear in your URL also. In your question `url_for` considered `filepath` to be a request parameter, and not a part of the URL.